# Can't fix ClassNotFoundException error?

Tags: java, applet, awt, classnotfoundexception

I'm sort of a beginner in java and i just started working on a project using an applet and the applet & stuff all works.. but every time i try running it i get this error:

```
--------------------Configuration: AlexVega - JDK version 1.8.0_20 <Default>     - <Default>--------------------
load: class Game.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Game.class
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(AppletClassLoader.java:219)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(AppletClassLoader.java:152)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(AppletClassLoader.java:634)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:799)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:728)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:378)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Process completed.
```

and here is my program:

```
package com.alexvega;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Game extends Applet{

private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;

public synchronized void start(){
    if(running)
        return;

    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(thread);
    thread.start();
 }

 public void run(){
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
double delta = 0;
long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
int updates = 0;
int frames = 0;
while(running){
long now = System.nanoTime();
delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
lastTime = now;
while(delta >= 1){
    int tick;
    updates++;
    delta--;
}
int render;
frames++;

if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
    timer += 1000;
    System.out.println("FPS: " + frames + " TICKS: " + updates);
    frames = 0;
    updates = 0;
}
}
}

public static void main(String args[]){

}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}
}
```

and here is the second part of the program:

```
package com.alexvega;

public class Window {

public Window(Game game){
    game.start();

}

}
```

What am i doing wrong???

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Comment: The HTML is part of the problem.  It apparently has something like `code='Game.class'` in the applet attribute when it should have `code='com.alexvega.Game'`.  It also needs to be in the correct path relative to the code base or code base/Jar.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It just means that your Java class could not be found/loaded at runtime, a very common issue for Java developers. From the error, it says `class Game.class not found` which is self explanatory.

You will need to set your classpath to tell the compiler where your classes are.

Check out [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) for instructions on how to set your classpath (for your Game class). There are also a lot more sites with instructions for this as well.

Happy coding.